# How do I import a DLL I created in Qt into a C# application

Tags: c#, qt, dllimport

I created a DLL in Qt with one function called `test`.  I created another Qt project in which I am able to use the DLL with no problems.  I now want to use this DLL in a C# app, however, I am having problems calling the function.  I have placed the DLL in the same folder as my C# exe.  I import the function like so

```
[DllImport("TestDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool test();
```

I receive the following exception:
`EntryPointNotFoundException`

I tried adding `EntryPoint = test` to my DllImport but still receive the same exception

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the test method is exported from the DLL?  Download the Dependency Walker and see if it is listed in the exports.  http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Don't need char set since there is no text and SetLastError = true is wrong, that's for win apis. Most likely your DLL has mangled names. Export it with a .def file to avoid mangling. Make sure you use extern "C". Also get the calling conventions to match. C++ code will use cdecl, your C# defaults to stdcall.

Comment: i have a feeling it might have something do to with the fact that i do not have a static build of qt installed.. not sure yet though

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing option in CharSet? I have been in similar situation. But at that time, I was using a third party Dll compiled in Fortran. Say may be try from Ansi to Unicode.

HTH

Comment: CharSet irrelevant since there are no text parameters here